# IServiceCollection Does not contain definition AddJsEngineSwitcher

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Trying to build ReactJS.NET in Visual Studio 2015

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore;
using React.AspNet;
```

In `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddReact();

    services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName)
        .AddChakraCore();

     services.AddMvc();
}
```

Got an Error to this part:

`AddJsEngineSwitcher`

> IServiceCollection does not contain definition for AddJsEngineSwitcher

Trying to fix some solutions but got no luck.

Checking also my Reference

`JavaScriptEngineSwitcher 3.0.0` is exists.

Also searching in Nuget package and changed `JavaScriptEngineSwitcher` but still the same.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/Registration-of-JS-engines#aspnet-core) show that you need to install this NuGet package, which contains the `AddJsEngineSwitcher` extension method that's missing:

[JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Extensions.MsDependencyInjection](http://nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Extensions.MsDependencyInjection/)

Once installed, you'll also need to add the following `using` to include the namespace:

```
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Extensions.MsDependencyInjection;
```

Comment: After adding this dependency, I'm getting an error **"The name ChakraCoreJsEngine does not exists in current context"**  on `ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName`.

Comment: I resolved the above mentioned issue by installing this `Nuget package`:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore/